# Can someone explain to me why my output is this? And how would I correct my output?

Tags: c++, stringstream

In this slice of code I get an output of

```
bbb 55 66 77 88
aaa
```

the output I expect and want is

```
bbb 55 66 77 88
bbb
```

because I reassign `ss` from `log[0]` to `log[1]`.
So my question is why is the output different from what I expect and how do I 
change it to what I want?

```
      int w,x,y,z;
      stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
      string word;
      string log[2];
      log[0]="aaa 11 22 33 44";
      log[1]="bbb 55 66 77 88";

      ss<<log[0];
      ss>>word;

      int k=0;
      ss>>w>>x>>y>>z;
      k++;

      ss<<log[k];
      cout<<log[k]<<endl;
      ss>>word;
      cout<<word<<endl;
      return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When

```
ss >> w >> x >> y >> z;
```

was executed, there is no content left to operate on and ss.good() returns false, which expresses the need to call ss.clear() in order to assure everything is ok and we can move on.

However, given that you do

```
ss.clear();
ss<<log[k];
```

The content of ss will be

```
aaa 11 22 33 44bbb 55 66 77 88
```

If you want it this way, fine.  But maybe you expected it to contain

```
bbb 55 66 77 88
```

which is done by

```
ss.str(log[k]);
ss.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write to the stringstream the second time the input pointer (tellg) is set to -1 and the fail bit is set.  That means neither the second write nor the second read succeed.

Comment: can I do anything that would make that not occur?

Comment: cout<<log[k]<<endl; 
is successful, so why not
cout<<word<<endl;

Comment: Why do you overwrite word before using the original value?

Comment: this is not my full code, just a slice that is causing the error, I do intend to rewrite, do something, rewrite, do something in a loop, so is it possible to reuse the "word"